# Laravel 5.8 Backpack addColumn custom type

Tags: laravel, sorting, dashboard, laravel-5.8, laravel-backpack

We are taking over a site and before rebuilding it we need to fix a few issues using

- **Laravel 5.8**
- **Backpack crud 3.6**

The dashboard shows all users (id, name, email) from the MySql **users** table, which is straight forward using

```
$this->crud->setFromDb();
```

Another column is created to display the status (active/inactive) of the user in relation to subscriptions stored in a different table as the users table.
This column uses the addColumn method with a custom column type like so:

```
$columnStat = [
                    'label' => "Status",
                    'type' => 'user_status',
                    'name' => 'id', // the db column for the foreign key
                    'key' => 'user_status', // this key helps to differentiate between column using same name
                    'entity' => 'subscriptions', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
                    'attribute' => 'user_id', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
                    'model' => "App\Models\UserSubscriptions" // foreign key model
            ];

$this->crud->addColumn($columnStat);
```

The custom type is defined in a blade file ***backpack/crud/columns/user_status.blade.php***:

```
@php
    $isActive = false;
    $user_id = $entry->{$column['name']};
    if(isset($user_id) && is_int($user_id)) {
        $subscription = \App\Models\UserSubscription::where('end_date', '>' , Carbon\Carbon::today())
                         ->where('payment_status', '=' , 1)
                         ->where('user_id', '=' , $user_id)
                         ->get()->last();
        if($subscription){
            $isActive = true;
        }
    }

@endphp

{{-- regular object attribute --}}
@if($isActive)
<td>Active</td>
@else
<td>Inactive</td>
@endif
```

The MySql table for user_subcriptions is the following:

```
mysql> desc user_subscriptions;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subscription      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date          | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id           | int unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| payment_status    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| deleted_at        | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**This is all working fine** (active and inactive are displayed correctly) except that **the column can't be sorted** in ascending or descending order.

The Backpackforlaravel docs show an example on how to improve the column to get a custom order:
(search internet for: backpackforlaravel.com and custom-order-logic-for-columns)

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
    // Select
   'label'      => 'Category',
   'type'       => 'select',
   'name'       => 'category_id', // the db column for the foreign key
   'entity'     => 'category', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
   'attribute'  => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
   'orderable'  => true,
   'orderLogic' => function ($query, $column, $columnDirection) {
        return $query->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'articles.select')
            ->orderBy('categories.name', $columnDirection)->select('articles.*');
    }
]);
```

I just don't understand how to implement this here in my case.

**My questions:**

- How can I modify the code to make the status column sortable in ascending or descending order?
- is there a way for me to output/log the query of the column so that I can understand how to modify it?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To view the query behind the column and log it, view the detailed answer given here: [How to see AJAX query behind list view in Backpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64145282/how-to-see-ajax-query-behind-list-view-in-backpack).  To add to this previous answer, if you have Laravel Debugbar (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) installed you can display the Backpack column query there using this: \Debugbar::info(asSql($this->crud->query));

Comment: To add to that, you can probably chain a ->dd() in the query statement.